# Is web worker heavier or lighter than a native thread

Tags: javascript, c++, multithreading, web-worker, emscripten

Is web worker just a normal native thread created by browser to run and communicate with other browser threads with a messaging queue? Or doesn't it contain other things when created?

I'm looking at the [experimental support of pthread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/emscripten-discuss/gQQRjajQ6iY) in emscripten, multiple threads in C++ will be translated to web workers once compiled. But will it have the same level of performance as native code? After all fine grained multithreading is a key feature in C++.

Comment: my guess is that web workers are just a threadpool in desguise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment, WebWorkers are pretty heavyweight because the VM duplicates a bunch of its internal state (sometimes even re-JITs code for a worker). That state is **much** bigger than a native thread's few MiBs of initial stack space and associated state.

Some of this can be fixed by implementations, and I expect that if [SharedArrayBuffer](http://tc39.github.io/ecmascript_sharedmem/shmem.html) or [WebAssembly](http://webassembly.org) + [threads](http://webassembly.org/docs/future-features/#threads) become popular then browser engines will want to optimize things.

That being said, the end of your question hints at a misunderstanding of what thread overheads are, and how the proposal for SharedArrayBuffer (which Emscripten relies on to support pthreads) works. WebWorkers are heavy at the moment, but they can communicate through SABs in exactly the same way native code such as C++ can: by accessing exactly the same memory, at the same virtual address. SAB adds a new kind of ArrayBuffer to JavaScript which doesn't get neutered when you `postMessage` it to another worker. Multiple workers can then see other worker's updates to the buffer in exactly the same way C++ code when you use `std::atomic`.

At the same time, workers can't block the main thread by definition and therefore have a more "native" feel. Some web APIs aren't available to all workers, but that's been changing. This becomes relevant if you e.g. write a game and have network / audio / render / AI / input in different threads. The web is slowly finding its own way of doing these things.

**The details are a bit trickier**

SAB currently only supports non-atomic accesses, and sequentially-consistent accesses (i.e. the only available `Atomic` access at the moment is the same as C++'s `std::memory_order_seq_cst`). Doing non-atomic accesses should be about as performant as C++'s non-atomics (big compiler caveats here which I won't get into), and using `Atomic` should be about as performant as C++'s `std::atomic` default (which is `std::memory_order_seq_cst`). C++ has 5 other memory orders (`relaxed`, `consume`, `acquire`, `release`, `acq_rel`) which SAB doesn't support at the moment. These other memory orders allow native code to be faster in some circumstances, but are harder to use correctly and portably. They might be added to future updates to SAB, e.g. through [this issue](https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript_sharedmem/issues/15).

SAB also supports `Futex` which native programs rely on under the hood to implement efficient `mutex`.

There are even trickier details when comparing to C++, [I've detailed some of them](https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript_sharedmem/issues/88) but there are even more.